# firing a git hook on the client

Tags: git

I updated "repo" from "computer 1". On "repo", a `post-receive` hook successfully fires to `git checkout -f` the changes to "computer 2".

Now, on "computer 2" I want to fire a hook once the above checkout is complete. I have tried a `post-receive` and a `post-checkout` hook on "computer 2" but have not been successful. Neither fires. Which hook could I use in this situation on "computer 2"?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just `git checkout -f`, because that means **repo1** is dumping its content on repo2 working tree:

```
 # repo1 post-receive hook
 GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/to/repo2 git checkout -f
```

What you need is for `repo2` to pull repo1 content in order to update its (`repo2`) content.
Plus, the fact that `repo2` initiates the update means that other repo2 hooks will have a chance to be triggered in turn.

```
 # repo1 post-receive hook
 GIT_DIR=/path/to/repo2/.git
 GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/to/repo2 git pull repo1
```