# Is --bare option equal to core.bare config in Git?

Tags: git

I want to create a git repo on my server to update my website after pushing. The first step of all tutorials(such as this: http://developertheory.com/how-to-auto-deploy-apps-after-git-push/) I found, is this command:

```
git init --bare
```

In the next steps I should enter the following commands:

```
git config core.worktree /path/to/git/deploy
git config core.bare false
git config receive.denycurrentbranch ignore
```

the second command (`git config core.bare false`) set the repo to non-bare. Why do we init the repo as bare and then set it to non-bare?!

Comment: Can you describe exactly what you are trying to do? What do you mean by "update my website after pushing"?

Comment: I mean I want to checkout automatically after I enter `git push` in my local system. Please see the url I just added to post

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this tutorial uses `git init --bare` as a "clean" way to create an empty repo which cannot be mixed with the actual files:

Such a repo will contain directly the `.git` usual content, even after being re-configure as non-bare.
You need a non-bare repo in order for the `git checkout` (in the hook) to work, since you can only checkout a branch in a non-bare repo (a bare one, by definition, has no working tree).

I wouldn't recommend that method for deployment though, and I prefer:

- keeping that repo bare in order to push to it
- setting up a *second* repo, non-bare
- adding a post-receive hook on the first (bare) repo in order for the second one to pull from what the first one just received.

See for instance:

- "[firing a git hook on the client](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11246504/6309)"
- "[Git checkout in post-receive hook: “`Not a git repository '.'`”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10507942/6309)"