# Synchronize github with godaddy account

Tags: github, synchronization, shared-hosting

I develop front-end and back-end of many websites hosted on godaddy. I was looking for a way to synchronize the godaddy file manager with my local repository so as to prevent me from uploading the edited files each time. I push my code to github directly, but is there a way to push the code directly to godaddy account without using its file manager?

Also sometimes, with other systems, I edit the code directly on the server if I get some problems with the code, which becomes then difficult to get it on my local system.

It would be of great help to directly push it without using the file manager each time.

Answer (score 4):

It would be best to:

- install Git on Godaddy (as in this [blog post](http://iamchuka.com/technology/installing-git-on-godaddy/))
- setup a bare repo on the upstream side (ie, the GoDady side, the one where you would push your code)
- add a post-receive hook on that upstream repo in order for a non-bare repo to update itself: see links in the "[Is `--bare` option equal to `core.bare` config in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14901796/6309)" answer.

Comment: Any more details on setting up a bare repo?

Comment: @AndrewTheis 5 years later, yes: git init --bare.